# Retrieve button name in Oracle Forms Builder after right click

Tags: plsql, oracleforms

I'm using Oracle Forms Builder. I have a button which has a pop-up menu attached to it. I need to retrieve the name of that button into a `text_item` after the user right clicks on it and selects one of the pop-up option.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. You want to get your item label into tex item?

Comment: I'm not that familiar working with pop-up menus but have you tried using :SYSTEM.Cursor_Item to get the name?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the name of the button clicked inside a trigger like when-button-pressed, then you can use the system parameter :system.trigger_item this will give you the item that fired the trigger. So if you use that in the when-button-pressed trigger you will get the item that pressed the button. 
If you start another application instead of just a popup or so and you need the item in that application then you can set a global or create a parameterlist with the itemname and then you can refer to that in the application you just started.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:SYSTEM.TRIGGER_ITEM`.

........